# find the top 5 for each from a file python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with the top names of each year male and female and i need to  find the top five for each, i have a little bit so far but not enought, can i get a little help.

```
# [import statements]
import q1fun
# [constants]

# [rest of program code]
f = open("customers.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
q1fun.names(f)

def names(f):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    [function description]
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Preconditions:
       [parameter name - parameter description (parameter type and constraints)]
    Postconditions:
       [returns: or prints:]
       [return value name - return value description (return value type)] 
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    f.seek(0)
    line = f.readline().strip()
    values = line.split(",")
    line_best = float(values[2])
    l = values

    if line_best == "m":
        for line in f:
            values = line.split(",")
            if line_best < float(values[3]):
                line_best = float(values[3])
                l = values

    else:
        for line in f:
            values = line.split(",")
            if line_best < float(values[3]):
                line_best = float(values[3])
                l = values

    return
```

Comment: What is the format of the customers.txt? Can you post a little bit from it?

Comment: This looks like homework, which we're not opposed to helping with, but you'll get a bit further if you post as much information as you have.

Comment: Emma,F,18787
Isabella,F,18590
Emily,F,17415
Olivia,F,17059
Ava,F,17021
Madison,F,17006

Comment: Darius,M,1049
Jerry,M,1044
Jaime,M,1040

Comment: Your code reads *one* line, sets `line_best` to the float of the 4th item, and then tries to compare that float to `'m'`. That will never work..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read your format; it is after all comma-separated. Python uses 0-based indexing, so the count is the column at index 2, not 3.

A [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) is the most efficient method of tracking the top N values of a given sequence

```
import csv
import heapq

male = []
female = []

with open('customers.txt', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        name, sex, count = row[0], row[1], int(row[2])
        heap = male if sex.lower() == 'm' else female
        if len(heap) < 5:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (count, name))
        else:
            heapq.heappushpop(heap, (count, name))

    # `male` and `female` now hold the 5 most common names
    # each list is a sequence of (count, name) tuples
    return sorted(male), sorted(female)
```

Comment: i keep getting an error for heapq saying its an unused variable

Comment: Sorry, the `import` line was missing, added that now.

Comment: i keep getting this error here                                   csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: Right, you are using Python 3 then; I've added that information to your question as a tag and updated my answer to work with Python 3 instead.

Comment: how do you have the list the other way around

Comment: Have *what* list the other way around?

Comment: the list that i print of for male and female

Comment: I build the list with `heapq.heappush()` and `heapq.heappushpop()` calls, adding `(count, name)` tuples. You need to do that so that `heapq` can compare two tuples by the `count` value.

Comment: If you were to reverse the tuples, you'd get the last 5 names in alphabetical order instead.